# media player issue while continuously click on button?

Tags: android, media-player

i am playing mp3 sound using default media player of android, my code for plying sound below

> ```
> MediaPlayer mp=MediaPlayer.create(hello.this,R.raw.abc);
>           if(mp!=null)
>           {
>               mp.start();
>           }
> ```

i need to play same sound on same button click. when i click continuously on button after some time sound is not working and i getting error MediaPlayer(7395): error (-19, 0).

Does any body have idea for this issue,
Please send me

Thank in advance.

Comment: disable button until your media player finish playing or you can set current position to 0 every time your button clicked

Comment: Thank for reply yes we can do it, but i think this is not correct way to solved this issue. i have found solution for this issue and i am also add code here..

Answer (score 2):

call

```
mp.reset();
```

because ever time you are decalaring object

or declare on class level Mediaplayer OBject

Answer (score 0):

Make global variable of mediaplayer and try this way

```
         MediaPlayer mp;

          if (mp!=null) {
              mp.stop();
              mp.release();
            }
          mp= MediaPlayer.create(hello.this,R.raw.abc);
          mp.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.create(this, R.raw.testmed);
    mp.setVolume(100, 100);
    mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mp.prepare();
```

Then you will need to define this and it should work:

```
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
       mp.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can play music like below

 // for play the song

     MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

                 try 
                {                   
                     mp.reset();
                     mp.setDataSource(songPath);                        
                     mp.prepare();
                     mp.start();                    
                     btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img_btn_pause);                   

                 } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution for this issue. i have correct this issue using below code, May help other also.

Thanks

Call Method like

```
PlaySound(R.raw.abc);
```

//Method

```
private void PlaySound(int Sound_id) 
    {
        mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(Act_Oceanwaves.this,Sound_id);
        if(mplayer!=null)
        {           
            mplayer.start();
        }
        mplayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
            {               
                mp.release();
            }

        });   


    }
```

Comment: what if your click your button two times, then two times your function called and two times your mplayer object get initialize two times.

Comment: actually i need to play different voice in diff button click, so i think it will release after complete of voice..

Comment: your solution is also right. right now i have use my solution for this issue even i will get any problem then i will try your way.